# cakePHP acl **ini** don't work (without database : **not DbAcl**)

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

i have a problem with CakePHP ACL in **ini configuration** : it's doesn't work.

I already follow this :

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html

it's very nice, but doesn't explain the main problem :

How the framework recognize ARO Group of my Users ?

and : What is "weapons" or "diplomacy" or other things like that ? Controllers ? Actions ? Magic formula to tell in order ACL to work (i know, it's not that... ;-) ) ?

So, searching and searching again, after some hours searching, i found the first main problem that it's not written in this tutorial : i have to configure the "authorize" parameter of the "Auth" plugin to "Actions".

Now, the Acl plugin is working, and doesn't authorize anything, but it's looping on a deny page... and only the login page is allowed.
What should i do ?

Comment: Did you read Cakephp's ACL tutorial? part 1 and part 2? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I already read all cake tutorials, but it's not what i want, everywhere in the web, it's DbAcl
but i want **INI Acl**

Comment: At the bottom of the page http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html#creating-acos-access-control-objects you find the `actionPath` configuration.

Comment: @q0re Already tried, i try again, it don't change anything. This is for DbAcl.